# copy sheet to other workbook using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting "error 9: subscript out of range" for the below code at line

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Allocation").Copy After:=Workbooks("\\Bmcstr01\grp\SRV\Allsrv\NEW Complaints Logger\GI Complaints\Spreadsheets\Archieve\Access_Log.xlsx").Sheets(Workbooks("\\Bmcstr01\grp\SRV\Allsrv\NEW Complaints Logger\GI Complaints\Spreadsheets\Archieve\Access_Log.xlsx").Sheets.Count)
```

Complete code:

```
Sub DASaveAs()
'MsgBox "SaveAs"
Dim namedate As String
namedate = Date
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Allocation").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Allocation").Copy After:=Workbooks("\\Bmcstr01\grp\SRV\Allsrv\NEW Complaints Logger\GI Complaints\Spreadsheets\Archieve\Access_Log.xlsx").Sheets(Workbooks("\\Bmcstr01\grp\SRV\Allsrv\NEW Complaints Logger\GI Complaints\Spreadsheets\Archieve\Access_Log.xlsx").Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = namedate
'Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\Bmcstr01\grp\SRV\Allsrv\2011 CRU\COMPLAINTS ADMIN FOLDER\Daily Allocation.xlsx"
'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Allocation").SaveAs ("\\Bmcstr01\grp\SRV\Allsrv\NEW Complaints Logger\GI Complaints\Spreadsheets\Archieve\ER Complaints - " & Format(Now(), "DD.MM.YYYY hhmm AMPM") & ".xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't copy to a workbook unless it's open. Once it's open its name does not include the path to the file. so

```
 Workbooks("\\Bmcstr01\grp\SRV\Allsrv\NEW Complaints Logger\GI Complaints\Spreadsheets\Archieve\Access_Log.xlsx")
```

Should be

```
Workbooks("Access_Log.xlsx")
```